# Extracting username and password from form in django

Tags: html, django, forms, twitter-bootstrap, django-authentication

I started working on a project in Django over half a year ago and put it on the back-burner because I couldn't figure out a small detail, but I'm back on the project and thought I could probably get a quick response here.

I'm got a mini-form which is in my toolbar on my site which is generated by the following HTML:

```
    <form action="/auth/" method="post" class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form"> {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="/register/">Signup</a>
  </form>
```

[image: Here's the result]

The goal is to avoid a separate login page and just have this in the top until the user logs in.

The goal is to use Django's authentication to log this user in.

```
def auth_view(request):
   email = request.POST.get('username', '')
   password = request.POST.get('password', '')
   print "username is ", email, "password is ", password
   user = auth.authenticate(username=email, password=password)

   if user is not None:
     auth.login(request, user)
     return HttpResponseRedirect('/loggedin/')
   else:
     return HttpResponseRedirect('/invalid/')
```

The above code is what I want to handle the click of the login button, as handed by my urls.py.
Any time I submit the form, however, my debug statement always says that the email and password are empty strings. Thus, I must be extracting the information from the form incorrectly.

How can I successfully login? Please help!

Thanks,
erip

Comment: How are you generating the form's HTML? I can't see `name` attributes for your inputs.

Comment: I don't really understand your question.

Comment: How are you generating the form's HTML you posted in your question? Are you using Django's templates or are you manually typing that HTML code?

Comment: I used a template from Bootstrap. I added the csrf_token, along with `action="/auth/" method="post"`, and the signup button. Everything else is from http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't get the values out of request object is both inputs have no `name` attribute. `request.POST.get('username', '')` tries to get the value of an input with a name attribute of `username`, which in your case does not exist. So add a `name` attribute and that should do it for you.

You can further utilize Django's forms module which automatically generates and assigns a `name` attribute for each field, eventually binding those inputs back to your login form. More on this on the official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/).

Comment: Added name="username" and name="password" and it worked like a charm. Thanks so much!